# Estructura de array en String a un String

Tags: java, array, arraylist, array-bidimensional

Tengo un problema.
Se me pasa por llamada la estructura de un array bidimensional, tal que:

`String arrayBidimensional="{{1,2,3,4,A},{4,7,8,5,B},{9,8,5,2,C},{7,5,3,2,D}}";`

Esto me llega como un String así, mi pregunta es ¿hay alguna forma de transformar esto en un Object[][]?

Es en java por si se requiere saber.

Porque por lo que he visto no puedo hacer.
Object matriz[][]=StringQueContieneLosDatos;

Comment: ¿Has investigado/intentado algo? ¿Qué no entiendes de lo investigado o qué problemas o errores tienes con lo que estás intentando?

Comment: @A.Cedano He investigado existe el .split() pero eso seria sobre un string limpio y no serviría para un array bidimensional. Por lo que no puede ser valido. Y no puedo hacer Object nombreString[][]= String contenido del array.

Comment: Explica qué significa *se me pasa por llamada* (¿llamada a qué o a quién, desde dónde, cómo, con qué herramientas?). Dí de dónde vienen los datos o, mejor aún, muestra el fragmento de código donde esos datos se producen. Digo esto porque si usas algún framework o algún contexto (como llamada a una API por ejemplo) puede haber formas simples de hacer lo que quieres, configurando la llamada que obtiene dichos datos.

Comment: hay la posibilidad que algún dato sea null?

Comment: @A.Cedano Me lo devuelve el método de lectura que es de donde obtengo el contenido de un archivo externo en TXT. El contenido me lo devuelve como el String mencionado arriba.

Comment: @Dramaturgo No, su mínimo en procesamiento seria {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dices que no se puede hacer usando `split()` porque no es un string limpio? Primero, no sé lo que es un string limpio, pero desde luego sí que se que se puede hacer perfectamente usando split!

```java
      String arrayBidimensional="{{1,2,3,4,A},{4,7,8,5,B},{9,8,5,2,C},{7,5,3,2,D}}";
      // Primero haces un split por "}," ya que todos los array internos se cierran justo antes de una coma
      String[] splitted = arrayBidimensional.split("},");
      Object[][] finalArray = new Object[splitted.length][5];
      for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++){
          // Lo más importante, eliminar los símbolos antes de hacer el siguiente split!
          finalArray[i] = splitted[i].replace("{","").replace("}","").split(",");
      }
      // Y ya podemos imprimir nuestro flamante Object[][] hecho con los split
      for(Object[] objArr:finalArray){
          for(Object o:objArr){
              System.out.print(o + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
```

Y la ejecución de ese método imprime exactamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ejecutarlo online [aquí](http://jdoodle.com/ia/lDu)

Comment: Esto es vergonzoso, que no supiera que se podían añadir mas elementos de separación al split es algo que no sabia. Gracias por la respuesta útil lo que yo entendía era que se podían separar por caracteres o por un único separador pero no por varios.

Comment: No hay vergüenza ninguna, ninguno nacimos aprendido! *El único ignorante es el que se niega a aprender* :)